# Amazon Connect with Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am uploading a segment file in Amazon Pinpoint and running a journey using the Amazon Connect contact centre.

In the segment file, I have added a column (Attribute) for example `campaignid` and I can see the attributes in Amazon Connect but when I am trying to add a block (check contact attributes) to the contact flow and check for the values I am not able to see it.

Does anyone know how to do it or check it?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this

Comment: Yes.I was able to solve it.

Comment: How did you manage to solve this?